# Invalid regular expression: /^?(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/:

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

This is my first ever posting on the stackover flow so excuse me if I am breaking any kind of rules.
I am trying to implement a tutorial related to "Make API on Node.js with express" and I am getting this error.

"Invalid regular expression: /^?(?:([^/]+?))/?$/:"

```
    var express = require('express')  
var bookRouter=express.Router();
var Book=require('/Users/home/Desktop/ExpressProject/Models/bookModels.js')
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
bookRouter.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        Book.find({}, (err, books) => {
            res.json(books)
        })  
    })
    .post((req, res) => {
        let book = new Book(req.body);
        book.save();
        res.status(201).send(book) 
    })

// Middleware 
bookRouter.use('/:bookId', (req, res, next)=>{
    Book.findById( req.params.bookId, (err,book)=>{
        if(err)
            res.status(500).send(err)
        else {
            req.book = book;
            next()
        }
    })

})
bookRouter.route('/:bookId')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.json(req.book)
    }) // end get Books/:bookId 
    .put((req,res) => {
        req.book.title = req.body.title;
        req.book.author = req.body.author;
        req.book.save()
        res.json(req.book)
    })
    .patch((req,res)=>{
        if(req.body._id){
            delete req.body._id;
        }
        for( let p in req.body ){
            req.book[p] = req.body[p]
        }
        req.book.save()
        res.json(req.book)
    })//patch
    .delete((req,res)=>{
        req.book.remove(err => {
            if(err){
                res.status(500).send(err)
            }
            else{
                res.status(204).send('removed')
            }
        })
    })//delete
    module.exports =bookRouter;
```

I am completely new to programming so also excuse if I am asking something to lame

Comment: you are not using `body-parser` anywhere. `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Comment: Can't find your regex in your code. What is the full error log? Could even be from `bookModels.js`...

Comment: Hi thanks for the prompt reply
I can't even reproduce this error anymore, The code editor fixed it itself and now its throwing something different.